# Is our Microservices Design Wrong?

Tags: rest, oop, architecture, microservices, cqrs

In our project, we are using micro services, and each micro service is making rest call to the same 3rd party service. As per my knowledge, we should make rest calls like `ms1 -> ms2`, where `ms2 -> 3rd party api`, instead we are directly getting data from `ms1 -> 3rd party api`.

1. So, are we doing it wrong? Or is my assumption wrong?
2. All our micro services are hitting the same 3rd party api. Do you think we can we apply concepts of eventsourcing and cqrs in this case? Or do you think can we apply messaging system concept in this case in order to improve the architecture?

What's your suggestion for the architecture?

**EDIT:**

**3)** The reason I've asked above bcoz, most of my microservices are using for loops and making rest calls to 3rd party api inside each for loop, so which means performance gets reduced. I am thinking that if we have some db in each of our microservice, so that whenever we make any GET 3rd party rest api call, then we can save that response in DB itself. And later when making further requests, will first check whether data exists in db , if yes, just return data from db , otherwise make rest call and save again new data in that respective microservice db. Does my thinking wrong?

**4)** Does making rest call faster or retreiving  data from DB is faster? Sorry, if its a dumb query..

Comment: Be careful not to over-engineering your solution. The architecture should be effective and the system maintainable. But your wording sounds as if you would like to have the best architecture and want to be very dogmatic. What's the problem of two micro services accessing a third-party problem? Don't increase the complexity if you don't have a problem.

Comment: Each Microservice should be as independent as possible and not call each other. Each Microservice calling a 3rd party service does not seem like a problem. It all really depends on what it does or if some of your Microservices calling it might be better of as a single service. Hard to tell from the current info. In general Event Sourcing is the storing of every change to the state of an application. CQRS is dividing your Reads and Writes into separate objects. I don't think either of those are in the context of this question though.

Comment: Okay, I agree with both above comments.. I will be glad to listen other views as well.

Comment: @Codo I've updated above.. May I know your opinion on above 3) and 4) points

Comment: @Nope I've updated above.. May I know your opinion on above 3) and 4) points

Comment: There are two hard problems in IT: 1) naming 2) cache invalidation. It's probably straight-forward to cache 3rd party data in a DB to increase performance. But do you understand when to refresh it? I see the challenge. It's probably not easy to solve. But without a detailed investigation, I can't recommend anything.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't think what you're doing is *inherently* wrong, there are a number of things you need to consider:

1. Temporal coupling / Availability: If during a single process you make multiple repeated calls to a third party service, you run the risk of increased unavailability
2. Service boundaries: If one service needs data from another, is the data ownership really correct? Does the service holding the data need, or uses all of the data, or does it use only a small subset?

I recommend you have a read on [microservices should be autonomous](https://xebia.com/blog/micro-services-architecture-principle-2-autonomy-overcoordination/), which cover the above points in more detail.

As for messaging, I strongly recommend those where availability is of high importance. Using asynchronous communication will solve the issue of temporal coupling (one service not being able to fulfill it's function while the other is not responding), which immediately increases availability, at the cost of higher windows for inconsistency or responding with stale data. The actual business impact of working on slightly stale data is (from experience) non-existent, but you will need to be aware of this fact to avoid surprises.

Event sourcing is a methodology I recommend highly in certain contexts, but it does come at a cost, and with a lot of gotcha's, so I don't recommend it as a default approach. It can yield surprising accurate results, with a very small number of bugs appearing after launch, but you need to have:

1. Direct access to domain experts, who are happy to engage the development team
2. A development team who is happy to work side-by-side with domain experts
3. A shift in mentality away from how we think about data when using normal form stores or document stores
4. While DDD isn't necessarilly a requirement, it does make the discovery process much easier and safer, so I'd strongly recommend you are at least aware of it.

#### UPDATE (to address edit)

Regarding your point 4: this depends on your design \ architecture, but most probably, it would be faster to hit your local db rather than make a remote call. You can use the same caching strategies to access the data (if that is needed for performance) in both microservices, but you'll have the cost of going over an additional network call to hit the remove microservice.

Regarding your point 3: Nothing changes from what I already suggested. Temporal coupling has a greater impact the more times you call the remote service, so you're making your situation worse by keeping the data outside of your service. The boundary argument again applies to a similar extent: if you need the data in another service, *maybe* you should look into the possibility that the data needs to belong to the second microservice which uses it **or** *part* of the data belong to one microservice and some other parts belong to the other.

In general, I was (and still am) suggesting that you keep a local copy of the subset of data that you need to do your operation, especially if this is a common operation.

Comment: I've updated above.. May I know your opinion on above 3) and 4) points

Comment: @john I don't think anything changes from what I said above, but I'll update the answer with more info.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to your question can be like,
There nothing correct or wrong in your design, But if you want to significantly improve your design then you use a message broker like Apache Kafka (Cost effective alternative can be hazelcast). This will definitely make your architecture strong/robust and failure resistant.
Second alternative can be like , Using some design pattern like facade and also having capability of doing async calls.
Note:I am new to this platform and in initial stages of answering. So any improvement suggested will be appreciated. Thanks.